# Delphi RAD Studio XE7 - no dbgrid component

Tags: delphi

I am trying to find `database grid` component (`FireDAC` driver), but there is nothing. I tried `dbgrid, TFDGrid`. I am using RAD Studio XE7 Architect.

Have someone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: TDBGrid is in the component palette in XE 7 when creating a VCL Forms application. It's been there since Delphi 1 was released, and has been in every version since up to and including Tokyo 10.2. It's unclear what you're asking; you can simply focus on the component palette and type `dbg` and it will appear for you. In Firemonkey (FMX) applications, there is no DBGrid; you use a TGrid instead with data bindings.

Comment: @Ken White, It is my problem. There is no 'dbg' and 'TDBGrid' when I type it in search bar.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense, unless you're creating a Firemonkey application instead. (See my comment above.) If you're creating something other than the VCL, you need to include that information in a tag or in the question text.

Comment: Are you in the designer? In the code editor visual components are not shown. Did you rename the component in the palette? Check "component toolbar" in environment options. Did you delete/hide the component from the palette? Unhide it or reset the palette by right clicking on the tool palette. Did you remove/uninstall the database components package? Check the packages list. Did you install cracked software? Don't do so.

Comment: Do you have the `dcldb210.bpl` package installed and enabled in your IDE?

Comment: In addition, the `TDBGrid` has nothing to do with FireDAC.

Answer (score 0):

I Do think that you are trying to create a multiplatform App (firemonkey). Create a windows VCL application and you will have the Data Access (datasource,...) and Data Control DBgrid and other components. Also, The Free Licence doesn't include the database components.

Embarcadero tells you to use the LiveBinding designer with a TStringGrid to simulate the DBGrid when creating multiplatform Apps.

Tips for VCL/Firedac: (create a datamodule where you drop your tfdconnection, and tfdtables), that way you will have access from all your projects units.